# Getting error -[__NSDictionaryM countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios6, gdata, picasa

I m using GData client library of google for picasa photos in my project .i have enable NSZombie setting in EDIT scheme under project so after enabling it console is showing this error **"-[__NSDictionaryM countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance "** .Piece of code where i m getting this error is

```
  for( GDataEntryPhotoAlbum * entry in [(GDataFeedPhotoUser *)result entries]){
                              @autoreleasepool {
                                  GRKAlbum * album = [self albumFromGDataEntryPhotoAlbum:entry];
                                  [albums addObject:album];
                              }
                          }
```

[for more info i have integrated grabKit third party framework in project](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit)

I have checked everything is fine regarding memory issues.

Comment: If you're getting a "**message sent to deallocated instance**" message, then everything is **not** fine regarding memory issues.  Try running with Instruments to see what has retained and released the zombie object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the developer of GrabKit. Thanks for using it :)

I have 2 questions :

_ Is your project under ARC ?

_ Does this error disappear when you disable NSZombie ?

Can you also give us a log value of 'entry' before it crashes ?

Thanks for helping on improving GrabKit :)

Comment: Thanks for reply.No my project is not under ARC.

Comment: Thanks for reply.No,my project is not under ARC and Yes this error disappear when NSZombie is disable.it is showing this message "message sent to deallocated instance" in Gdatautilites.m class in below code  escapedStr = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                       originalString,
                                                       leaveUnescaped,
                                                       kCharsToForceEscape,
                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

Comment: Your project should use ARC to use GrabKit properly. This is the origin of your error :)